# how to install libio-socket-ssl-perl on tiny core Linux?

Tags: linux, ssl, perl

I found this commands on another pages:

> apt-get install libio-socket-ssl-perl
>
> tce-load -wi libio-socket-ssl-perl

but doesnt work.

Any idea to install **libio-socket-ssl-perl** on tiny core Linux?

Comment: What's the output of `tce-load -wi libio-socket-ssl-perl`?

Comment: Downloading: libio-socket-ssl-perl.tcz

wget: server returned error: HTTP/1.1 404 Not found

connecting to distro.ibiblio.org

wget: server returned error: HTTP/1.1 404 Not found

md5sum: libio-socket-ssl-perl.tcz.txt: no such file or directory

error on libio-socket-ssl-perl.tcz

Answer (score 2):

`libio-socket-ssl-perl` is the Debian package name for the [`IO::Socket::SSL`](http://search.cpan.org/~sullr/IO-Socket-SSL-1.74/SSL.pm) Perl module.

It can be installed directly from [CPAN](http://www.cpan.org/) using `cpan` or the simpler [`cpanm`](https://raw.github.com/miyagawa/cpanminus/master/cpanm) commands (note: you will need the OpenSSL libraries installed first).

```
# cpanm IO::Socket::SSL
```

Comment: If you don't want to use cpanm, this work: `cpan -i  IO::Socket::SSL`